# Docker container OS and host OS on Windows incompatibility skip OS validation?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am hitting incompatibility with Docker OS container and Host OS.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.724GB
Step 1/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909-amd64
1909-amd64: Pulling from windows/servercore
a Windows version 10.0.18363-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.17763 host
```

I have seen other SO threads where a workaround would be to update Host OS to match targetting container OS version.

Is there any way how to skip this pull validation?

We are using **VMs only to build docker images and ship them**, not to run containers (even though docker build creates containers along the way).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way except to change the system
I had once encountered such issue where I was using amr64 machines for amd64 images and it didnt work

https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-190-exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error/49368/5
https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-190-exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error/49368/5

Usually compatibility info of any image you will get in this output
you can try it on your system for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909-amd64

```
docker manifest inspect ‐‐verbose rust:1.42-slim-buster
[
{
"Ref": "docker.io/library/rust:1.42-slim-buster@sha256:1bf29985958d1436197c3b507e697fbf1ae99489ea69e59972a30654cdce70cb",
"Descriptor": {
"mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
"digest": "sha256:1bf29985958d1436197c3b507e697fbf1ae99489ea69e59972a30654cdce70cb",
"size": 742,
"platform": {
"architecture": "amd64",
"os": "linux"
}
},
"SchemaV2Manifest": { ... }
},
{
"Ref": "docker.io/library/rust:1.42-slim-buster@sha256:116d243c6346c44f3d458e650e8cc4e0b66ae0bcd37897e77f06054a5691c570",
"Descriptor": {
"mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
"digest": "sha256:116d243c6346c44f3d458e650e8cc4e0b66ae0bcd37897e77f06054a5691c570",
"size": 742,
"platform": {
"architecture": "arm",
"os": "linux",
"variant": "v7"
}
},
"SchemaV2Manifest": { ... }
...
]
```